# How to escape "[]" chars in regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I have a stream, which has the following expression:

```
.map(l -> l.replaceAll("[,.!?:;]", "")
```

As you can see I want to take a string, and if a string contains one of the values ,.!?:; I want to remove them.

I also want to remove These two symbols: [     ]

When I add it in the sequence:

```
.map(l -> l.replaceAll("[,.!?[]:;]", "")
```

The idea gives me an error, unclosed character class. How can I include these two symbols in the sequence as well?

Comment: Know that has nothing to do with the stream, but with regex

Comment: I will keep in mind thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You escape special characters with `\`. Note that `\` is itself a special character. So something like

```
.map(l -> l.replaceAll("[,.!?\\[\\]:;]", "")
```